# "Main thread" in Threads pane in one project but not in others

Tags: delphi

In debugging one of our projects, I have this icon with the title "Main thread" in this Threads pane:

[image: Project One]

But in other projects, I do not have that icon:

[image: Project Two]

This gets my attention because it happened during the migration of my projects from Delphi XE to Delphi 10.3.1.

Comment: Have you code in the project that gives a name to that thread?

Comment: Nop, i have not code naming thread in my project

Comment: Do some libraries use threads?

Comment: Most likely, the one project has a specific component or library that explicitly names the main thread in its code, whereas the other project does not have that same component/library.

Comment: Yes , thank you Remy LeBeau , it is EurekaLog in the project 
But it is called also when it is desactivated also , abnormal ...

Comment: I would still think something somehwere in the project is naming this thread. Try setting a breakpoint in `TThread.NameThreadForDebugging` to find out if anything calls into it.